# Scipy: Union of sparse boolean matrices

Tags: merge, scipy, boolean, sparse-matrix

In Scipy, what is the most efficient way to get the union `A+B+C` of multiple boolean sparse (`csr`) matrices `A,B,C` (with the same shape)?

Union means among others:

- sparsity changes
- overlaps are possible

Answer (score 2):

Just add them:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
x = sparse.csr_matrix([[True, True, False], [False, False, False], [True, False, False]] , dtype=bool)
y = sparse.csr_matrix([[False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False]], dtype=bool)
print((x + y).todense())
>>[[ True  True False]
 [False  True False]
 [ True  True False]]
```

**EDIT**

If you want to access the indices directly, you can use `coo` format (which allows retrieving row and col index), stack the indices and use `np.unique` (disclaimer: I haven't checked for efficiency comparison):

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
c2=sparse.eye(5, k=1, dtype=bool, format='coo')
c1=sparse.eye(5, dtype=bool, format='coo')
c3 = c1.copy()
c3.row, c3.col = np.unique(np.hstack((np.vstack((c1.col, c1.row)),np.vstack((c2.col, c2.row)))), axis=1)
c3.data = np.ones(c3.row.size, dtype=bool)
c3.todense()
>> matrix([[ True, False, False, False, False],
    [ True,  True, False, False, False],
    [False,  True,  True, False, False],
    [False, False,  True,  True, False],
    [False, False, False,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is inefficient. I was wondering if I can quickly merge the data in the background (i.e. data, indices, indptr).

Comment: I added a way to get the indices in the background and work with them: `coo` format allows that. Note: Maybe you can find something more efficient (I also haven't tried speed comparison).